# C language program is detected as a virus

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, antivirus, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
union abc
{
    int a;
    int x;
    float g;
};
struct pqr
{
    int a;
    int x;
    float g;

} ;

void main()
{
    union abc b;
    struct pqr c;
clrscr();
b.a=10;
textbackground(2);
textcolor(6);
cprintf(" A = %d",b.a);
printf("\nUnion = %d",sizeof(b));
printf("\nStructure = %d",sizeof(c));
getch();
}
```

I have saved this program as virus.cpp. I am using Turbo C compiler to compile this program and run from Turbo C (Ctrl + F9).

I am using Windows 7 and I have installed Avira AntiVir virus system.

When I tried to run above program, it creates a worm (DOS/Candy). I believe there is nothing wrong in program.

[alt text](http://i41.tinypic.com/9sdjb8.jpg)

Now here is something special. Execute the same program with following difference. Here the only difference is space between `\n`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
union abc
{
    int a;
    int x;
    float g;
};
struct pqr
{
    int a;
    int x;
    float g;

} ;

void main()
{
    union abc b;
    struct pqr c;
clrscr();
b.a=10;
textbackground(2);
textcolor(6);
cprintf(" A = %d",b.a);
printf("\n Union = %d",sizeof(b));
printf("\n Structure = %d",sizeof(c));
getch();
}
```

The difference is only \n and space. My question is, why is my simple program is detected as virus?

Here is another code sample, this time for C++:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class A
{
    int a,b;
public:
    A()
    {
        a=0;b=0;
    }

    A(int x)
    {a=x;
    b=0;
    }

    A(int x,int y)
    {
    a=x;
    b=y;
    }

    ~A()
    {
    cout<<"All things are deleted.";
    }

    void get()
    {
    cout<<"\nA = "<<a;
    cout<<"\nB = "<<b;
    }
};

void main()
{

A a1(5,10);
clrscr();
a1.get();
getch();
}
```

When I run this program it gives "Virus Warning" - Even it is not an virus. Now, the tragedy is when you remove destructors, it won't detect it as virus.

Here is the screen shot and similar question:

[C Language - \n - creating virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443166/c-language-n-creating-virus)

[alt text](http://i41.tinypic.com/9sdjb8.jpg)

The question is how, and why?

Comment: Just out of curiosity:  why are you using a 20 year old compiler?

Comment: No doubt, this virus evolves from the undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: Your compiler is converting your program to a virus because you used `void main`. :-)

Comment: @James McNellis - Your comment is great. But we have to have to follow this compiler strictly - Just because it is in our University syllabus. ( Yes, it looks ridiculous - but it is the fact. We are forced to follow the syllabus instructions ). I know today many other compilers are available. But I had no choice. Because In practical examination we have to give our exam on turbo c only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like a false-positive.  Because modern viruses use polymorphism to hide from anti-virus programs, the anti-virus program has to report even partial matches, and apparently your compiler with the given source code produces a partial match to that malware.

Answer (score 19):

Virus scanners use heuristics and signatures to detect vulnerabilities. False positives are unavoidable. Your program seems to trigger the heuristic. Presumably its checksum, file size or other characteristics match a known virus. This is seconded by the fact that a small change is sufficient to resolve the problem.

**EDIT** Calling your application **Virus.exe** is a pretty unfortunate choice, and I'd presume it will trigger most virus scanners quickly (although it's certainly not a perfect name for a real virus ...).

Comment: ... and maybe the fact that the OP calls his programs `VIRUS` and `VIRUS2` helps to get the anti-virus software to think that it's found a virus...?

Comment: Hey ! You might use other name also. I had too many programs on my disk for my exam preparation - I just named it like this just because - I wanted to identify it easily. You might choose other name - then also it will detect it as virus.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a real virus somewhere, that perhaps have modified the standard libraries :D
Or simply the antivirus detects a pattern in the executable.

Comment: No - It's not there. I need answer - not any assumptions. I have verified too many times. First I formatted entire computer - Installed os & then first antivirus system & then turbo c. Even After this - it is detecting my program as virus.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.viruslist.com/en/viruses/encyclopedia?virusid=1857 .

My guess is that Antivir scans through text strings that DOS/Candy contains, and since the one in the second piece of code is like the one it's looking for, Antivir detects the compiled executable as a virus.